# summernote buttons are not appearing

Tags: jquery, summernote

I download the css and js of summernote. Then I import this files before close the body element. I also added the id "summernote" to a textarea element:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Textarea</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="summernote" name="summernote" rows="3"></textarea>
 </div>
```

But on the page the summernote buttons dont appear. It is just appearing a resize button at the bottom of the textarea.Do you know why?

**The head element is like this:**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Laravel</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" " crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

**Then before close the body element I have:**

```
<body>

<link href="http://layout.test/css/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://layout.test/css/summernote.js"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
    });
  });

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: This tag: `<link href="http://layout.test/css/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />` must be in `<head></head>` section instead of `<body></body>`.

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheet needs to be referenced in the `<head>` area of the page, also you haven't included an element inside the `<body>` for the editor to be rendered in. For e.g. `<div id="summernote"></div>` or inside a `<form>` area you can use `<textarea id="summernote"></textarea>`.